# contextmenu (CytoscapeJs vs AngularJs)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, cytoscape.js

I have a problem in my project which uses angularjs and cytoscape.js
I have a question about contextmenu for cytoscape.
Documentation give us some examples with plugins [qtip](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-qtip) and [contextmenu](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu). 
 But in my case I must have right-click menu like jquery-bootstrap-context-menu, if you know. 
I looked for how connect jquery libraries and cytoscape, but it didn't help me. (all answers told me that it is a bad idea, but I hope situation in this case changed, because all answers was about 2 years ago).
Thank you very much, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

(1) Use a dummy DOM element per graph element.  See the qtip extension code for an example of how this is done.

(2) Manually position your menu at `node.renderedPosition()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I chose d3 instead of cytoscape. :)